# Church encoded Free monad in F#

Tags: f#, existential-type, free-monad, rank-n-types

I am trying to express the Church encoding of the Free monad in F#. `Free` is specialized to a particular functor, `Effect`.

I am able to write both `return_ : 'T -> Free<'T>` and `bind: ('T -> Free<'U>) -> Free<'T> -> Free<'U>` without any problems.

A sketch of my implementation is given below.

```
type Effect<'T>
    = GetStr of (string -> 'T)
    | PutStr of string * 'T


module Effect = 

    let map (f: 'a -> 'b) : Effect<'a> -> Effect<'b> = function
        | GetStr k -> 
            GetStr(f << k)

        | PutStr (s,t) -> 
            PutStr(s, f t)


type Free<'T> =
    abstract Apply : ('T -> 'R) -> (Effect<'R> -> 'R) -> 'R

module Free = 
    let inline runFree (f:Free<'T>) (kp: 'T -> 'R) (kf: Effect<'R> -> 'R) : 'R = 
        f.Apply kp kf

    let return_ (x: 'a) : Free<'a> = 
        { new Free<'a>
            with
                member __.Apply kp _ = 
                    kp x
        }

    let bind (f: 'a -> Free<'b>) (m: Free<'a>) : Free<'b> = 
        { new Free<'b>
            with
                member __.Apply kp kf = 
                    runFree m
                        (fun a -> 
                            runFree (f a) kp kf
                        )
                        kf
        }
```

When I try to write an interpreter for this encoding, I hit a problem.

Given the following code:

```
module Interpret = 

    let interpretEffect = function 
        | GetStr k -> 
            let s = System.Console.ReadLine()             
            (k s , String.length s)

        | PutStr(s,t) -> 
            do System.Console.WriteLine s 
            (t , 0) 

    let rec interpret (f: Free<string * int>) = 
        Free.runFree
            f
            (fun (str,len) -> (str,len))
            (fun (a: Effect<Free<string*int>>) -> 
                let (b,n) = interpretEffect a 
                let (c,n') = interpret b 
                (c, n + n')
            )
```

I get a type error in the third argument to `Free.runFree` within the `interpret` function:

```
...

(fun (a: Effect<Free<string*int>>) -> 
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ------ Expecting a Effect<string * int> but given a Effect<Free<string*int>>
```

I understand why this is happening (the result type of the first function determines `'R === string*int`) and suspect that can be solved using a rank-2 function (which can be encoded in F# e.g. http://eiriktsarpalis.github.io/typeshape/#/33) but I am not sure how to apply it.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Michael

Comment: Can you review your code samples? Second argument to `Apply` doesn't type check.

Comment: @scrwtp, thanks, fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to do anything there, the compiler suggested type is in fact correct (and in line with the type of `runFree`).

It seems that what you're thinking of there is Scott encoding (ripped from [this Haskell question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31398516/how-do-i-use-the-church-encoding-for-free-monads?rq=1)):

```
runFree :: Functor f => (a -> r) -> (f (F f a) -> r) -> F f a -> r
```

where `F f a` would be your `Effect`-specialised `Free<'a>`, and `f (F f a)` would be `Effect<Free<'a>>`, which is what you're trying to use.

Whereas Church encoding would be:

```
runFree :: Functor f => (a -> r) -> (f r -> r) -> F f a -> r
```

where `f r` is `Effect<'a>` - thus making it easier to express in F# (which is why I assume you're using it in the first place.

This is what I had for `interpret`:

```
let rec interpret (f: Free<string * int>) = 
    Free.runFree
        f
        (fun (str,len) -> (str,len))
        (fun (a: Effect<_>) -> 
            let (b,n) = interpretEffect a 
            let (c,n') = interpret (Free.pureF b)
            (c, n + n')
        )
```

where `pureF` is

```
let pureF (x: 'a) : Free<'a> = 
    { new Free<'a> with member __.Apply kp _ = kp x }
```

i.e. your `return_` function.

I think defining the corresponding `freeF` function would clear some things (like why is `Effect<'a>` a functor - you're not making use of this fact anywhere in the code you pasted).